# Jquery select product from td

Tags: jquery, select, html-table

I have a table that looks like the following (simplified):

```
<table id="product_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        <tr rel="1">
            <td>Product Name 1</td>
            <td class="select_product">[SELECT]</td>
        </tr>

        <tr rel="2">
            <td>Product Name 2</td>
            <td class="select_product">[SELECT]</td>
        </tr>

        <tr rel="3">
            <td>Product Name 3</td>
            <td class="select_product">[SELECT]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to bind a click event to the td / or content within it (not yet decided) and use the id contained in the parent tr's rel (the product id) in a call to a function 'view_product' for arguments sake.

I've tried a stack of combinations but I'm not getting anywhere.

Any pointers?

---

**Solution**

```
$('td.select_product').bind('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
    $.select_product(id);
});
```

Placed after the table rows are generated. I'm not sure that binding it multiple times is the best solution by any means but it works.

Comment: If you change `bind` to `live` in your solution it will work even after new rows are added without rebinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('td.select_product').bind('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
    $.select_product(id);
});
```

Placed after the table rows are dynamically generated.

I'm not sure that binding it multiple times is the best solution by any means but it works.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to be able to bind a **click** event to the **td** / or content within it (not yet decided) and use the **id** contained in the **parent** tr's **rel** (the product id) in a call to a function '**view_product**' for arguments sake.

your language translates (more or less) into the jQuery syntax:

```
$("td.select_product").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
    view_product(id);
});
```

---

Try this for binding a click event if the items are created dynamically using [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$("#product_table").delegate(".select_product", "click", function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
    view_product(id);
});
```

Comment: It looks right but still not having any luck. The table is generated dynamically so I assumed it wasn't working because the table elements hadn't been created at the point the bind is 'registered'. I've tried moving it to after it is but no change.